# Equivalence relation on measurable functions in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space. For measurable functions $f,g: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ let $f \sim g$ if $f$ is almost everywhere equal to $g$.

I already showed that $\{x \in \Omega \space| \space f(x) \neq g(x) \}$ is measurable.

How do I show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on measurable functions in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Show that $f \sim f$, show that if $f \sim g$ then $g \sim f$ and finally if $a \sim b, b \sim c$ show $a \sim c$.

Comment: Note that for measurable $f,g$,  $f \sim g$ **iff** the set $\{ x | f(x) \neq g(x) \}$ has measure zero.